# Agrupar e somar arrays com propriedades iguais

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

```
x [{produtoId: 5, quantidade: 10},
   {produtoId: 6, quantidade: 20},
   {produtoId: 5, quantidade:  7}]

y[{produtoId: 5, quantidade: 17},
  {produtoId: 6, quantidade: 20}]
```

Preciso transformar o array X no array Y alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de implementar utilizando laços `for` é a seguinte:

```
const x = [{produtoId: 5, quantidade: 10},
   {produtoId: 6, quantidade: 20},
   {produtoId: 5, quantidade:  7}]
   const y = []
   let inserir = true;
  for (let i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j< y.length;j++) {
      if (y[j].produtoId === x[i].produtoId) {
        inserir = false;
        y[j].quantidade += x[i].quantidade;
      }
    }
    if (inserir) {
      y.push(x[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(y)
```